# OCSP command-line test tool?

Tags: java, python, command-line, ocsp

Does anybody know of a tool to test OCSP responses? Preferably, something that can be used from a Windows Command-line and/or can be included (easily) in a Java/python program

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking a bit more, I think I've found some answers:

a) OpenSSL at the rescue:

```
openssl ocsp -whatever
```

For more info, http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/ocsp.html

b) http://www.openvalidation.org/ is another way of testing a cert. And via its links, I got to:

- http://security.polito.it/tools/ocsp/
- Ascertia OCSP Client tool (http://www.ascertia.com/products/ocsptool/)
- Ascertia OCSP Crusher tool (an OCSP load generator) (http://www.ascertia.com/products/ocspCrusher/)

Thanks to all the answers!

Comment: `openssl ocsp -issuer ca_cert.pem -cert server_cert.pem -text -url http://ocsp.provider.com` is the full command.

Answer (score 1):

The newpki client claims to be able to do that.
http://www.newpki.org/

Comment: Thanks a lot, Alexey.

The newpki client seems to be a bit more complex than I look for, as it's a full PKI admin tool

Answer (score 1):

bouncycastle has a Java crypto-provider and support for OCSP requests and responses. The differences between OCSPReq and OCSPRequest and OCSPResp and OCSPResponse class are a little confusing, though.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good ressource to have a simple OCSP Client or OCSP Responder with OpenSSL : http://backreference.org/2010/05/09/ocsp-verification-with-openssl/

Answer (score 0):

Can you test it over HTTP as described in the specs in Appendix A?  If so, then you can use any web test util.  Since you mentioned Java, [JMeter](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/) comes to mind.  With JMeter, you can create your java code to do validation, etc and re-use it in your test cases.

Can you use something other than CMD line, such as a BASH script via [Cygwin](http://cygwin.com)?

You'd still have to script some things to validate the test, perhaps using [openssl](http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/ocsp.html)?

```
curl http://some.ocsp.url/  > resp.der
openssl ocsp -respin resp.der -text
```

See page http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2560.txt

Comment: curl http://some.ocsp.url/  > resp.der?? What time you passed the DER Certificate Status Request??